# nuxt js with vuetify, why do not add style?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

**nuxt js with vuetify, why do not add style?**
why I can not add style to my nuxt project like this "nuxt js with vuetify, why do not add style?"

*full code*

[image]

[image]

*package.json*

```json
{
  "name": "itc-seer-landing",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "lint:js": "eslint --ext \".js,.vue\" --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "lint:style": "stylelint \"**/*.{css,scss,sass,html,vue}\" --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "lint:prettier": "prettier --check .",
    "lint": "yarn lint:js && yarn lint:style && yarn lint:prettier",
    "lintfix": "prettier --write --list-different . && yarn lint:js --fix && yarn lint:style --fix"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "cookie-universal-nuxt": "^2.2.2",
    "core-js": "^3.25.3",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "vue": "^2.7.10",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.7.10",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.10",
    "vuetify": "^2.6.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.19.1",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^11.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^3.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/stylelint-module": "^4.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.12.3",
    "eslint": "^8.24.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.5.1",
    "postcss-html": "^1.5.0",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "stylelint": "^14.13.0",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "^9.0.3",
    "stylelint-config-recommended-vue": "^1.4.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^28.0.0"
  }
}
```

I can not add style to my nuxt project like this "nuxt js with vuetify, why do not add style?"

Comment: Could you please format your question properly? Also, how do you inject your style? It looks like an error related to stylelint, not your css.

Comment: Fixed the formatting. And yeah, check the error at the given line.